# I can access my samba server via hostname, but not via ip

Tags: linux, samba

There is a SAMBA server with a very basic configuration:

```
[share]
   path = /srv/samba
   force group = users
   create mask = 0660
   directory mask = 0771
   browsable =yes
   writable = yes
   guest ok = no
```

Its very creative hostname is "server".
I can access it fine via `\\server\share`, get asked my credentials and am on my way.
If I access via `\\192.168.0.24\share` my credentials are rejected.
My client is Windows 10.
I double checked the ip address.

Any pointers what is going on?

Comment: Type in server\username for your username.

Comment: @Appleoddity didn't work

Comment: Your using two slashes at the beginning of your UNC path right? `\\server\share`

Comment: @Appleoddity yes, using file:// doesn't change anything either